# Search by Category Name with here API

Tags: here-api

I would like to make a search based on a category: education-facility.

When I tried to put it in the q, it does not work.

Is it possible with here auto suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all categories in Here API are permanent and applicable to every location. Some categories are locally relevant(to a particular location). You can check the categories relevant to your location using

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&at=52.50449,13.39091
&pretty
```

Below is an example of a location where education-facility is available: 
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?at=41.8369%2C-87.684&cat=education-facility&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

To read more about entrypoint categories use developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-place-categories.html

Comment: Hi support team, do you have a demo website for the Discover or Browse API like what you shared above?

Browser API
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-browse-brief.html

Thanks!